# How to add specific number in last row from UserForm using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am the beginner of VBA and need some help from you in code.

My problem is that I want to make some kind of UserForm using VBA in Excel to generate new numbers for new ticket.

The UserForm will be needed to manage tickets about received problems.

The case is that I want to make new number of ticket by clicking button "New Ticket". After that, in UserForm, the "Ticket Number" field will be blocked and show assigned new ticket number, "Date Opened" field will show current date automatically and "Accept" button will change text to "Create" button and will be enabled. After clicking "Create" button, UserForm will close and write line about ticket with details in last row in Excel sheet.

I also want to have ticket number starting with specific number e.g. 60555, 60556, 60557 etc. The problem is that now I am receiving numbers 1, 2, 3 etc.

Below you can see some screenshots of problem and part of created code.

[UserForm "Manage Tickets"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk15U.png)

[After "Create" button, what is showing in last row in Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVmvj.png)

[What I want to show in last row in Excel Sheet after "Create" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MKuL.png)

If there is a way also to show text "**[BHD#?????]**" in UserForm and add it by UserForm, it will be very helpful for me!

Part of code which is responsible for "New Ticket" button:

```
Private Sub btwNewTicket_Click()
    ClearFields
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issue Log").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row - 4
    Me.tbTicketNo.Value = LastRow
    Me.tbTicketNo.Locked = True
    Me.tbDateOpen = Date
    Me.btnAccept.Caption = "Create"
    Me.btnAccept.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! (+Well written question, thanks!)  I'm a fan of Excel and it's countless capabilities but this is one of the times my first thought is...  What you want is very do-able, but when you start using Excel as a database you may be better off to switch to Access.  Access is as easy (or easier) than Excel to learn, and everyone who has Excel probably has Access, which is designed specifically for these kinds of tasks.  Forms are more user friendly, data is easier to store & share in an organized and secure manner, corruption is far less likely, and scale-ability is practically unlimited.

Comment: ...however 100% of the times I suggest that, there are reasons that the person doesn't want to use Access.  I don't have time to look at your question in depth but I'm sure someone will have a solution for you... but not as easy as unique field names would be in Access.  :-)

Comment: Thank You ashleedawg for your quick comment! :) Unfortunatelly I can use only Excel and migrate to Access is not a solution for me at the moment. Unique field names are not so important as specific numbers for now if it is so complicated to make.

Comment: There's always a reason.  :-)  Where are the ticket numbers stored?  I assume in column `B` of `Sheets("Issue Log")`?  If so, is it fair to say that the next ticket number would be the [`MAX` value in column `B`] `+ 1`?

Comment: They can be stored in other sheet, for example "Sheet2" or "Internal", not the same where I want to manage tickets.

Comment: I think you should open different questions for every of your needs. 1 for the last row thing, 1 for concatenating stuff, and more.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm not sure about what you writed. Can you advise what you mean by "open different questions"?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings with the `&` symbol. Hence a possible solution for your needs would be:

```
Me.tbTicketNo.Value = "[BHD#" & Format(LastRow,"00000") &"]"
```

The `Format(LastRow, "00000")` makes the value always five digits long. With `LastRow=1` the output would be `[BHD#00001]`.

If you want to start by a value of `60555` than just add this value

```
Me.tbTicketNo.Value = "[BHD#" & 60555+LastRow &"]"
```

With `LastRow=1` the output would be `[BHD#60556]`

Comment: Hello sporc, it looks very nice and useful in UserForm just I was looking for! Unfortunatelly there is showing me some kind of error, when I want to click "Create" button: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"?